# Rails test:models dump after having added an index

Tags: postgresql, macos-catalina, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm developing a ruby application using Ruby 2.6.3, Rails 6.0.2.2 and Postgres 12.

Everything was running fine, until I added an index to a table using a migration:

```
class AddIndexToUserEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

Running `rails test:models` return the following infinite dump, and I wasn't able to get rid of.

Any help will be appreciated

```
% rails test:models
Run options: --seed 62890

# Running:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    20: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    19: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
    18: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
    17: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
    16: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
    15: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
    14: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
    13: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
    12: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    11: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1138:in `method_missing'
    10: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1158:in `with_friend'
     9: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `block in method_missing'
     8: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1227:in `open'
     7: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
     6: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1251:in `send_message'
     5: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:929:in `send_request'
     4: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `send_request'
     3: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `each'
     2: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:611:in `block in send_request'
     1: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:565:in `dump'
/Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:565:in `dump': no _dump_data is defined for class PG::Connection (TypeError)
    25: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    24: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
    23: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
    22: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
    21: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
    20: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
    19: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
    18: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
    17: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    16: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1138:in `method_missing'
    15: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1158:in `with_friend'
    14: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `block in method_missing'
    13: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1227:in `open'
    12: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
    11: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1251:in `send_message'
    10: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:929:in `send_request'
     9: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `send_request'
     8: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `each'
     7: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:611:in `block in send_request'
     6: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:564:in `dump'
     5: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:567:in `rescue in dump'
     4: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `make_proxy'
     3: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `new'
     2: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1101:in `initialize'
     1: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1807:in `to_id'
/Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1738:in `current_server': DRb::DRbServerNotFound (DRb::DRbServerNotFound)
    25: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    24: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
    23: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
    22: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
    21: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
    20: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
    19: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
    18: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
    17: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    16: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1138:in `method_missing'
    15: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1158:in `with_friend'
    14: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `block in method_missing'
    13: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1227:in `open'
    12: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
    11: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1251:in `send_message'
    10: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:929:in `send_request'
     9: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `send_request'
     8: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `each'
     7: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:611:in `block in send_request'
     6: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:564:in `dump'
     5: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:567:in `rescue in dump'
     4: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `make_proxy'
     3: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `new'
     2: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1101:in `initialize'
     1: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1807:in `to_id'
/Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1738:in `current_server': DRb::DRbServerNotFound (DRb::DRbConnError)
    11: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    10: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
     9: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
     8: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
     7: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
     6: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
     5: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
     4: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
     3: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in start'
     2: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:97:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in start'
     1: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:97:in `each'
/Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:98:in `block (3 levels) in start': undefined method `exception=' for #<Minitest::UnexpectedError: Unexpected exception> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    20: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    19: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
    18: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
    17: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
    16: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
    15: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
    14: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
    20: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    13: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
    19: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
    12: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    18: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
    17: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
    11: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1138:in `method_missing'
    16: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
    10: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1158:in `with_friend'
    15: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
     9: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `block in method_missing'
    14: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
     8: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1227:in `open'
    13: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
     7: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
    12: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
     6: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1251:in `send_message'
     5: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:929:in `send_request'
     4: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `send_request'
     3: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `each'
     2: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:611:in `block in send_request'
    11: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1138:in `method_missing'
     1: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:565:in `dump'
/Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:565:in `dump'  10: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.: 0/drb/drb.rb:1158:in `with_friend'
     9: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `block in method_missing'
no _dump_data is defined for class PG::Connection (  8: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1227:in `open'
TypeError    7: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
     6: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1251:in `send_message'
)    5: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:929:in `send_request'

     4: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `send_request'
    25: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
     3: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `each'
    24: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
     2: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:611:in `block in send_request'
     1: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:565:in `dump'
/Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:565:in `dump':     23: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
no _dump_data is defined for class PG::Connection ( 22: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
TypeError   21: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
)
    20: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
    25: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    19: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
    18: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
    17: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    16: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1138:in `method_missing'
    24: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
    15: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1158:in `with_friend'
    14: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `block in method_missing'
    13: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1227:in `open'
    12: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
    23: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
    11: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1251:in `send_message'
    10: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:929:in `send_request'
     9: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `send_request'
     8: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `each'
    22: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
     7: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:611:in `block in send_request'
    21: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
     6: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:564:in `dump'
    20: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
     5: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:567:in `rescue in dump'
    19: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
     4: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `make_proxy'
    18: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
     3: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/   17: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `new'
    16: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1138:in `method_missing'
    15: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1158:in `with_friend'
    14: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `block in method_missing'
    13: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1227:in `open'
     2: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1101:in `initialize'
    12: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
    11: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1251:in `send_message'
     1: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1807:in `to_id'
    10: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:929:in `send_request'
/Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1738:in `current_server': DRb::DRbServerNotFound    9: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `send_request'
 (   8: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `each'
DRb::DRbServerNotFound   7: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:611:in `block in send_request'
)    6: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:564:in `dump'

     5: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:567:in `rescue in dump'
     4: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `make_proxy'
    25: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
     3: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `new'
    24: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
     2: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1101:in `initialize'
     1: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1807:in `to_id'
/Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1738:in `current_server':  23: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
DRb::DRbServerNotFound (    22: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
DRb::DRbServerNotFound  21: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
)   20: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
    19: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
    18: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
    17: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    16: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1138:in `method_missing'
    15: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1158:in `with_friend'
    14: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `block in method_missing'
    13: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1227:in `open'

    12: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
    25: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    11: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1251:in `send_message'
    10: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:929:in `send_request'
    24: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
     9: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `send_request'
    23: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
     8: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `each'
    22: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelizat   7: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:611:in `block in send_request'
ion.rb:74:in `map'
    21: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
     6: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:564:in `dump'
    20: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
     5: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:567:in `rescue in dump'
    19: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
     4: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `make_proxy'
    18: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
     3: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:650:in `new'
     2: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1101:in `initialize'
    17: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
     1: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1807:in `to_id'
/Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1738:in `current_server'   16: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1138:in `method_missing'
:   15: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1158:in `with_friend'
DRb::DRbServerNotFound (DRb::DRbConnError   14: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `block in method_missing'
)
    11: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
    13: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1227:in `open'
    12: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
    10: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:138:in `run'
    11: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:1251:in `send_message'
     9: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
    10: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:929:in `send_request'
     8: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
     9: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `send_request'
     7: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
     8: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:610:in `each'
     6: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
     7: from /Users/pdipietro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/drb/drb.rb:611:in `block in send_request'



... more dump existed but limited to 30000 characters
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to the last minitest version (5.14). They have [fixed](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38424) that in rails but the fix has not been released yet

Open you gemfile and explicitly set your minitest version:

```
gem 'minitest', '<=5.13'
```

then run `bundle update minitest`. It will then show you what the real issue with your database in your error message.